# Missing 5 points for writings in my Careers profile even though I do have items in that section

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

Although I have completed my [Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/madd0), the Completeness Score is still missing 5 points because it thinks I haven't entered anything in the *Writing* category.

[image: Completeness score missing 5 points]

Except that I did enter stuff:

[image: Writings section with data in it]

I don't really care about the points, since they're visible only to me, but it looks like a bug, so I'm reporting it. I also may be doing something wrong so I tagged this both "support" and "bug". You can retag if necessary.

In any case, all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the report.  That section of the report was a bit misleading.  We've switched it to be "Reading" and "Writing" (including books or articles in each) instead of just Books and Articles.  All scores have been recalculated.